# Why does Qt QString's replace method mutate the QString?

Tags: c++, qt, replace, mutable

I work with a number of `const QString&` objects in my current Qt code. Replacing parts of the string is a common occurrence across a large number of QStrings in different contexts. Unfortunately, Qt has the `replace` method mutate the owning QString (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace).

I often find myself needing to do this:

```
// (note that mClass->DType() returns a `const QString&`)
QString modifiedName = mClass->DType();
modifiedName.replace("*", "");
SomeOtherFunction(modifiedName);
```

...instead of this (which AFAIK won't work):

```
// (note that mClass->DType() returns a `const QString&`)
SomeOtherFunction(mClass->DType().replace("*", ""));
```

Is there a better way to do this? Why is the QString's `replace` method mutating the QString?

Comment: *Why* Qt does it is subjective, probably because they think that's the better API. As for getting around it, you can always copy it on the same line you run the replace function: `QString(mClass->DType()).replace("*", "")`

Comment: "Why is the QString's replace method mutating the QString" - Because that's how they chose to implement it. Could they have chosen differently? Yes. Did they? No. Deal with it.

Comment: The interesting thing is I have rarely found myself in this situation. And I have written hundreds of thousands of lines of Qt code in the 10 years I have written Qt applications at work.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Fair, I'm just curious. I'm more surprised there's no `replace(...) const` variation, there's only the mutable kind.

Comment: @Justin I suppose that would work, actually. I haven't thought about that. I suppose that's similar to what a const replace would do.

Comment: @Zzzach... The various [replace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace) overloads don't suit you? If you want to operate on a copy, then just *make* a copy.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The various overloads are nice, but each one "returns a reference to this string" instead of returning a different object. If you have a `const QString` and try to call `replace`, it will error since there is no `replace(...) const` variation (emphasis on **const**), no?

Comment: @Zzzach... Sure. So you just make a copy and operate on the copy. This is no more expensive than if Qt did that internally. Cheaper even, in the many cases where you *don't* want a copy.

Answer (score -1):

Your assigning a const to a non-const object. Much like you could assign a non-const to a const. Some API's don't like this, but Qt isn't picky.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: By buffering the non const object it is implicitly mutable bc its no longer const... by trying to change the const buffered string as listed by op in the code that didnt work of it makes sense if it doesnt work bc that buffer is const. Do that not answer the question?

Comment: Since he used assignment op he created a new string that wasnt specified const... this is technically a bad q.